# A little complex message layout

Tags: android, layout, kotlin

I have a very interesting problem. I should make a layout for a text message like in telegram, but only with text. So i should shift timestamp a little bit down if text of message take more than 1 lines. 
I made layout with 2 textViews (one for single line message and other for multiline, you can see my layout in attach)

My problem is that when i show timestamp for multiline case all list a little jump (because height of view change)
Here my code from my viewHolder (i use kotlin, but it still very obvious).
The main question is - how i can calculate line count in textView before render?

```
   val date = stamp.toString(Constants.DEFAULT_TIME_FORMAT)
   textViewItemMessageText.text = text
   textViewItemMessageTimeForSingleLine.show()
   textViewItemMessageTime.hide()
   textViewItemMessageTimeForSingleLine.text = date
   textViewItemMessageText.post {
   if (textViewItemMessageText.lineCount > 1) {
       textViewItemMessageTimeForSingleLine.hide()
       textViewItemMessageTime.show()
       textViewItemMessageTime.text = date
   }




<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/thin_green"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewItemMessageText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textColor="@color/black_light_87"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                tools:text="My generation"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewItemMessageTimeForSingleLine"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_read"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/grass_two_54"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                tools:text="16:20"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewItemMessageTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_read"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@color/grass_two_54"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            tools:text="16:20"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```